# Why can I not encrypt/decrypt HMAC keys for database storage?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, aes, hmac

I generate random HMAC keys for each user and store the key in our database. The user only gets the key if they request it, and most often just uses our API tokens (SWT) as BASE64 encoded opaque keys and don't worry about their integrity.

I want to encrypt the keys before storing them in our SQL Server database to prevent the keys from being compromised. They encrypted keys get stored in a varbinary(MAX) column. Everything works great without the encryption.

I'm using AES for the encryption with a randomly generated IV that is stored at the beginning of the encrypted value.

In my unit tests with simple strings, all is well, however, with HMAC keys, the decrypted value never matches the original. As in, if I generate an HMAC key, encrypt it, store it in the database. When I retrieve it, decrypt it, and use they key to generate an HMAC hash, it does not match the original HMAC hash value.

See the encryption/decryption methods below.

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] value)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt));

            aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.GenerateIV();
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var crypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);

                    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                    {                            
                        bw.Write(value);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }

                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] value)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt));

            aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(value))
            {
                byte[] iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];

                ms.Read(iv, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                aes.IV = iv;

                using (var crypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The password and salt are stored in const string literals compiled into the code. I realize this is not ideal, but it is what it is for now.

Comment: You've given some code, but not said in what way it doesn't work...

Comment: If I generate an HMAC key, encrypt it, store it in the database. When I retrieve it, decrypt it, and use they key to generate an HMAC hash, it does not match the original HMAC hash value.

Comment: So what have you done to diagnose the problem? Have you logged the bytes involved at every stage? (Before encryption, after encryption before saving to the database, after fetching from the database but before decryption, after decryption...) Basically, you need to isolate exactly what stage is causing the problem.

Comment: (First problem that I see is that you're encrypting the IV, but then reading that as if it's in plaintext... you should be able to prove that that's the problem without involving the database at all. Next problem I see is that you're reading the data as a string for no obvious reason...)

Comment: Right, so my IV is not the same as the original. Would this cause a false positive on a unit test with a short string like "blah"?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know... but you should be in a good position to find out for yourself.

Comment: This is a bit of a newb question, but how do I return a byte array without first going to a string? I see your point, I just didn't know of anything other than using a StreamReader and calling ReadToEnd() which returns a string.

Comment: One way is to keep reading a buffer at a time and write it into a MemoryStream, then you can call ToArray on that. See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/readbinary.html which is rather old, but should still be valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was two fold. The first, as discussed with Jon Skeet was that the IV was being encrypted and therefor was different when used to decrypt the value. I corrected this in the following code by writing directly to the MemoryStream instead of the CryptoStream.

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] value)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt));

            aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.GenerateIV();
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var crypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
            {
                ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                bw.Write(value);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

The next part I'm not completely sure about, but I do think Jon was also correct about there being some issue with reading into a string and back to a byte array. I corrected this by using some code similar to his found here: [jonskeet.uk/csharp/readbinary.html](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/readbinary.html) to read a stream directly into a byte array. See the following code where ReadStream() is the method I wrote based on Jon's.

```
public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] value)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_salt));

            aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(value))
            {
                byte[] iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];

                ms.Read(iv, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                aes.IV = iv;

                using (var crypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                   return ReadStream(cs, 0, ms.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help Jon. I also appreciate you not just giving it away. I don't mind working for it if I'm going to learn something. It's what I get paid to do.

Answer (score -1):

How about something simple and custom?

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace GrimoireTactics.Framework.Security
{
    public enum ObfuscatorType
    {
        Encrypt,
        Decrypt
    }
    public class Obfuscator
    {
        private string _seed;
        private byte[] _hashedSeedBytes;
        private readonly SHA256Managed _hashingAlgorithm;
        public string Seed
        {
            get
            {
                return _seed;
            }
            set
            {
                this._seed = value;
                SeedHash = GenerateHash(value);
                this._hashedSeedBytes = GetBytes(SeedHash);
            }
        }

        public byte[] SeedBytes
        {
            get
            {
                return _hashedSeedBytes;
            }
        }

        public string SeedHash { get; private set; }

        public Obfuscator(string seed)
        {
            this._hashingAlgorithm = new SHA256Managed();
            this.Seed = seed;
        }


        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
        {
            return Transform(data, ObfuscatorType.Encrypt);
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(string data)
        {
            return Transform(GetBytes(data), ObfuscatorType.Encrypt);
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
        {
            return Transform(data, ObfuscatorType.Decrypt);
        }

        public byte[] Transform(byte[] bytes, ObfuscatorType type)
        {
            int passwordShiftIndex = 0;
            byte[] data = bytes;
            byte offset = 0;
            switch (type)
            {
                case ObfuscatorType.Encrypt:
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                    {
                        byte currentByte = _hashedSeedBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
                        offset += (byte)(1 + currentByte); // Incrementing Offset
                        data[i] = (byte)(data[i] + currentByte + offset);
                        passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % _hashedSeedBytes.Length;
                    }
                    break;
                case ObfuscatorType.Decrypt:
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                    {
                        byte currentByte = _hashedSeedBytes[passwordShiftIndex];
                        offset += (byte)(1 + currentByte); // Incrementing Offset
                        data[i] = (byte)(data[i] - currentByte - offset);
                        passwordShiftIndex = (passwordShiftIndex + 1) % _hashedSeedBytes.Length;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return data;
        }

        public byte[] GetBytes(string data)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        }

        public byte[] GetBytes(string data, Encoding encoding)
        {
            return encoding.GetBytes(data);
        }

        public string GetString(byte[] data)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        }

        public string GetString(byte[] data, Encoding encoding)
        {
            return encoding.GetString(data);
        }

        public string GenerateHash(string text)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            byte[] hash = _hashingAlgorithm.ComputeHash(bytes);
            string hashString = string.Empty;
            for (int index = 0; index < hash.Length; index++)
            {
                byte x = hash[index];
                hashString += $"{x:x2}";
            }
            return hashString;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GrimoireDevelopmentKit.DevelopmentKit.UserInterface;
using GrimoireTactics.Framework.OpenGL.Modeling;
using GrimoireTactics.Framework.OpenGL.Texturing;
using GrimoireTactics.Framework.Security;

namespace GrimoireDevelopmentKit.DevelopmentKit
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new DevelopmentKitEditor());

            Obfuscator obs = new Obfuscator("My Arbitary Seed");
            byte[] obufsicatedData = obs.Encrypt("Some Top Secret Data");
            byte[] unobufsicatedData = obs.Decrypt(obufsicatedData);
            Console.WriteLine(obs.GetString(unobufsicatedData));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

All we do is obfuscate the bytes using a custom algorithm. Code is free to use for anyone; I just use it as an added security measure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm not really looking for something weaker than AES. I have AES working as designed above now, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @EvilAugust There are different measures of "Secure". AES is equally as secure as my custom algorithm, because it's impossible to hide security keys. In the end, obufsucation is all that matters. My code encrypts and decrypts fast and provides 1:1 size ratio. Plus, the complexity of the algorithm makes it way too time consuming to crack.